# Delta Lake throwing ProtocolChangedException when running two jobs concurrently for disjoint partitions

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

I am trying to run two different instances of Apache Spark + Delta Lake job on AWS S3 concurrently. Each instance is processing an independent parquet file which will be written to a disjoint partition in the Delta Table. Irrespective of the files and partitions being independent to each other, I am running into below error.

```
delta.exceptions.ProtocolChangedException: The protocol version of the Delta table has been changed by a concurrent update. This happens when multiple writers are writing to an empty directory. Creating the table ahead of time will avoid this conflict. Please try the operation again.
Conflicting commit: {"timestamp":1670947072124,"operation":"WRITE","operationParameters":{"mode":Overwrite,"partitionBy":["PartitionColumn"]},"isolationLevel":"Serializable","isBlindAppend":false,"operationMetrics":{"numFiles":"1","numOutputRows":"30915","numOutputBytes":"7007784"},"engineInfo":"Apache-Spark/3.3.1 Delta-Lake/1.2.1","txnId":"58a1c854-13a6-475e-bb0b-cfe2146441cc"}
```

I tried overwrite and append modes hoping to see if it makes any difference. But no luck. Ideally, I should have the ability to run the job concurrently for 'n' number of disjoint partitions without any exceptions.

Here is my code snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, current_date, col, when
from delta import *
from delta.tables import *
import time

spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("PySparkLocal")\
            .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")\
            .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")\
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")\
            .config("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore")\
            .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.2.1")\
            .config("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")\
            .config("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", "true")\
            .config("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "gzip")\
            .config("spark.databricks.delta.changeDataFeed.timestampOutOfRange.enabled", "true")\
            .getOrCreate()


INPUT_DATA_PATH = "s3://inputFile.parquet" --when I launch two different jobs in parallel, I provide different input files from the same folder.
DELTATABLE_PATH = "s3://DeltaTable"

deltaData = spark.read.parquet(INPUT_DATA_PATH )
deltaData.write.format("delta").option("overwriteSchema","true").partitionBy("PartitionColumn").mode("overwrite").save(DELTATABLE_PATH)
```

Comment: Eventhough you provide different files but does those files have same value of the PartitionColumn... If you could share the sample source data in both the files someone could help you out with what the issue could be

Answer (score 0):

Because S3 doesn't provide necessary functionality, you need to have a coordinator that will allow multiple writers.  Instead of `S3SingleDriverLogStore` you need to use `S3DynamoDBLogStore` that will use DynamoDB for coordinating writes. You can get more information about it in the [announcement blog post](https://delta.io/blog/2022-05-18-multi-cluster-writes-to-delta-lake-storage-in-s3/) and in [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#multi-cluster-setup).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I was using Delta Lake 1.2.1 earlier and upgrading to 2.1.1 has fixed this error.